# For Oh-My-ZSH, where do I put UNIX commands I want to executed when a new instance is started

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to have `set -o vi` run on every instance of my iTerm window. I know there is a file that I can add this to, but Im not sure which one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set -o vi` is equivilent to `bindkey -v`, which is the way I'd normally enable that particular option.

As with all `zsh` options, you can put it in the `zsh startup files` (ie, `~/.zshrc`). The use of `oh-my-zsh` does not inhibit your ability to use `~/.zshrc` yourself.